# How to rotate numpy 3D array around its center given a rotation matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy.ndimage

I have a **3D** numpy array with `shape=(50, 50, 50)` which I would like to rotate around center, **using a rotation matrix R**.

I am trying to do this by using `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform`, but I'm open to better suggestions.

This is the code that shows the problem:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy
from PIL import Image

R = np.array([
    [ 0.299297976, -0.817653322, -0.491796468],
    [-0.425077904, -0.575710904,  0.698473858],
    [-0.854242060,            0, -0.519875469],
])
print('Is R really orthogonal:', np.allclose(np.dot(R, R.T), np.identity(3)))  # True

# initialize some random data:
a = (50 + np.random.rand(50, 50, 50)*200).astype(np.uint8)
print(a.shape)  # (50, 50, 50)
Image.fromarray(a[:, :, 25]).show()

b = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(a, R, offset=0)
Image.fromarray(b[:, :, 25]).show()

c = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(a, R, offset=(50, 50, 50))
Image.fromarray(c[:, :, 25]).show()
```

[image: original]

[image: rotated with offset 0]

[image: rotated with offset 50]

What is unexpected to me is that:

- rotating with offset `0` doesn't seem to rotate around the center
- looking at the last image, the operation this matrix does is not just a rotation, but some kind of warping / shearing also

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** the answer by @Nin17 is correct, this is the version that is adapted to original (3D) problem:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy
from PIL import Image

R = np.array([
    [ 0.299297976, -0.817653322, -0.491796468, 0.],
    [-0.425077904, -0.575710904,  0.698473858, 0.],
    [-0.854242060,           0., -0.519875469, 0.],
    [          0.,           0.,           0., 1.],
])

N = 50

shift = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, N / 2],
        [0, 1, 0, N / 2],
        [0, 0, 1, N / 2],
        [0, 0, 0,     1],
    ]
)
unshift = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, -N / 2],
        [0, 1, 0, -N / 2],
        [0, 0, 1, -N / 2],
        [0, 0, 0,      1],
    ]
)

print('Is R orthogonal:', np.allclose(np.dot(R, R.T), np.identity(4)))  # True

a = (50 + np.random.rand(N, N, N)*200).astype(np.uint8)
print(a.shape)  # (50, 50, 50)
Image.fromarray(a[:, :, N//2]).show()

b = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(a, shift @ R @ unshift, offset=0)
Image.fromarray(b[:, :, N//2]).show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this link help? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html

Comment: I think this solves a problem of creating a rotation matrix, not applying it to the 3D array? (I would love to be proven wrong however)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation for `affine_transform`, it states:

`Given an output image pixel index vector o, the pixel value is determined from the input image at position np.dot(matrix, o) + offset.`

Therefore, a pure rotation matrix will rotate the array around the pixel at index (0, 0) (in 2d). In order to rotate around the centre of the image, you could apply translations before and after the rotation to shift the image coordinates such that the centre is at (0, 0) perform the rotation, and then shift the image back, in 2d this could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import affine_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


rng = np.random.default_rng()

theta = rng.random() * np.pi * 2
rotation2d = np.array(
    [
        [np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0.0],
        [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ]
)

N, M = 50, 51

image = rng.random((N, M))

shift = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, N / 2],
        [0, 1, M / 2],
        [0, 0, 1], # need to also apply shift on third axes for 3d array
    ]
)
unshift = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, -N / 2],
        [0, 1, -M / 2],
        [0, 0, 1], # need to also apply shift on third axes for 3d array
    ]
)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(affine_transform(image, rotation2d))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(affine_transform(image, shift @ rotation2d @ unshift))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Woohoo, thank you so much! :) Yes, this was the reason. I have now adapted your example for 3D and will edit the question with it. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The first question was answered by @Nin17. As for the second question:

> looking at the last image, the operation this matrix does is not just a rotation, but some kind of warping / shearing also

I do not think you are seeing a shearing but rather the effects of intersection of the output image's plane with the cube (your input image). Depending on your rotation matrix, that plane may cut a corner of the cube. If you define the rotation to be around one of the axes of the cube, you will not see this anymore. For example:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
R = Rotation.from_euler('z', 45, degrees=True).as_matrix()
```